# DD-WRT & Comcast SMC Modem

Tags: dd-wrt, voip, smc

My office has a comcast business modem (SMC something) which is garbage and so I took a Netgear WNDR3400 and put DD-WRT on it to use it as the DHCP server. Per [this](https://blacklineconsulting.com/2015/07/07/how-to-switch-your-smc-comcast-business-gateway-into-bridged-mode/) article I added the router as a DMZ and the SMC modem was 10.1.10.1 and i set the netgear subnet to 192.168.1.0/24. That was fine except the VoIP gateway had a static IP in the 10.1.10 subnet and so the phones stopped working. If I changed the netgear subnet to 10.1.10.0/24 with a starting IP of .2 or .3 it wouldn't work.

Is there a way to make it work in the net 10 subnet or is the best practice to change the setting in the phones to the 192.168 subnet??

Sorry if this is missing necessary information and thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How can we know what/if you can do that to your phones when you provided no information about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same subnet on both the WAN and LAN sides of a router; so the easiest course of action would be to change the subnet between the LAN of the SMC and the WAN of the Netgear to something other than 10.1.10.X, and then set the LAN subnet on the Netgear to be the 10.1.10.X needed by the phones.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was so focused on router settings that I didn't think to just swap them. Sorry about the phones, I guess what I really meant was "is there a way I can do this without changing all the phones?" Thank you!